# Kohen-accessible Cenotaph

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, architecture-design, cemetery-grave

Scenario: An architect is building an extension onto a cemetery. As it will engulf the section traditionally reserved for Kohanim, he wishes to build an "overpass" with cenotaphs holding the information from the matzevot. The "overpass" would be built from tumah-resistant materials, but would likely have windows. It would be immediately above the kevarim, but accessible only from outside of the cemetery.

Would such a structure be kosher for Kohanim to enter?

Comment: I don't see any way of answering this question without blueprints

Comment: @DoubleAA, then this would be a question of practical halachah, which would be off bounds. I'll try to make something though.

Comment: What does "tumah-resistant materials" have to do with accessibility for Cohanim?

Comment: @danny If something is not tumah resistant then it cant chotzeitz

Comment: @DoubleAA - even if it's permanently connected to the ground?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Ohel has different rules for those types of things.

Comment: @YeZ, can you elaborate? The classic Ohel is a "sheet" held up with poles and connected to the ground so it doesn't fly away. Mishnayot talk about its status under the extra pieces that lie in the ground. Also about the status of touching the outside of the cloth with the Tum aon the inside.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Tumas Ohel has different rules for kabbalas tumah, namely the rules of chotzetz bifnei hatuma. Mechubar l'karka is a rule in kabbalos tumah, which may or may not apply to tumas ohel, but is certainly not chotzeitz.

Answer (score 4):

In order to prevent Tuma from rising, you need a  Tefach space covered by a roof.

To achieve this for a *bridge*, you use the  כיפין על גבי כיפין concept, as described by the Para Aduma ceremony, where they had a bridge from the Temple Mount to Har Hazeitim:

> [מסכת פרה - פרק ג - משנה ו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01358.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2)
>
> וְכֶבֶשׁ הָיוּ עוֹשִׂים מֵהַר הַבַּיִת לְהַר הַמִּשְׁחָה, כִּפִּין עַל גַּבֵּי כִפִּין, וְכִפָּה כְנֶגֶד הָאֹטֶם, מִפְּנֵי קֶבֶר הַתְּהוֹם, שֶׁבּוֹ כֹהֵן הַשּׂוֹרֵף אֶת הַפָּרָה, וּפָרָה וְכָל מְסַעֲדֶיהָ, יוֹצְאִין לְהַר הַמִּשְׁחָה:‏

Essentially a series of arches on top of arches, so that every *foot* of the second floor is resting on a hollow, so as to cover all available Tuma-leakage.

Or as the Bartenura explains:

> רגלי הכיפה שהכיפה נשענת עליהם נקראין אוטם. ואין רגלי הכיפה העליונה כנגד רגלי התחתונה, אלא כנגד הכיפה עצמה, דכנגד אוטם העליונה עומד חלל התחתונה

Alternately you could use a long hanging/suspension bridge that maintains a height of at least 1 Tefach above any graves.

Windows are not a problem as long as the Cohanim don't lean out of them (Oholos [11:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.11.4)) and they don't have a ledge that would bring in the Tuma, as explained by the Rambam in [הלכות טומאת מת פרק יז.](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a117.htm)

Comment: A window that has a window ledge might bring tumah into the bridge through the window space. Looking for an explicit source for that now.

Comment: @Shokhet - only the "upper" window "ledge". Or if the window ledge is hollow. See Rambam in הלכות טומאת מת פרק יז http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a117.htm

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's what I meant.

Comment: Why would someone DV this answer?

Comment: @Shokhet FWIW it appears the downvote predates all the edits.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even so; the first rev was fine, I think.

Comment: @Shokhet - I'm used to it. Most of my answers get anonymous DVs. I must have stepped on somebody's toes once too often. :-)